# Scala message passing order

Tags: scala, message-passing

I've written a Scala program which in it, in a method I send 3 messages to another actor. Can I be sure that these messages are received in destination in order which I sent them?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka documentation, [Message Delivery Reliability](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html), *Discussion: Message Ordering*:

> ... for a given pair of actors,
>   messages sent directly from the first to the second will not be
>   received out-of-order.

Note that there is no guaranteed delivery, so any message can be lost. For instance: sent `{1, 2, 3}` - received `{1, 3}`.